# What is the name of this type of treatment in video/audio?

Tags: audio-quality

I ran into an expression a couple of months ago to describe videos which involve audio that is very present, as a way to heighten the senses. An example of this can be found here:

I'm looking for the name of that expression... It was something like high sensory experience or something similar but I've looked up a bunch of different names and couldn't find it. Would anyone know what I am talking about? It's often used in the context of filming people who are working with their hands and I know there are playlists of these types of videos around on YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

It's also known as having an solid understanding of microphones and recording techniques, as well as sound audio editing principles. These types of videos are a great example of how awesome sound recording can enhance picture, and examples of the reason no filmmaker should skimp on sound. It's easier to mess up good sound for dramatic effect (say, adding EQ for distortion or making it quieter and adding reverb to make it sound farther away), but near impossible to clean messed up sound to make it usable.

Comment: CICO as they say... (crap in, crap out)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up finding it myself in the end:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_sensory_meridian_response